# Cron Process Hangs Indefinitely In Logrotate

Tags: linux, bash, cron, logrotate

I currently have a server that **isn't rotating it's logs daily** has intended. The `logrotate` itself is most likely the one making my `cron` process hang.

I have to kill the process manually every time after the `cron` runs, so it can run again the next day.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux | grep cron
root     15364  0.0  0.0 116884  1304 ?        Ss   Sep12   0:03 crond
root     17898  0.0  0.0  19060   972 ?        Ss   Sep13   0:00 /usr/sbin/anacron -s
root     17911  0.0  0.0 106112  1272 ?        SN   Sep13   0:00 /bin/bash /usr/bin/run-parts /etc/cron.daily
root     17915  0.0  0.0 106112  1140 ?        SN   Sep13   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
root     17916  0.0  0.0 105968   900 ?        SN   Sep13   0:00 awk -v progname=/etc/cron.daily/logrotate progname {?????   print progname ":\n"?????   progname="";????       }????       { print; }
root     22439  0.0  0.0 103320   856 pts/0    S+   09:53   0:00 grep cron
```

As can bee seen in the logs, the job is locked by another `anacron`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# tail /var/log/cron
Sep 16 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[22374]: starting 0anacron
Sep 16 09:01:01 localhost anacron[22386]: Anacron started on 2016-09-16
Sep 16 09:01:01 localhost anacron[22386]: Job `cron.daily' locked by another anacron - skipping
Sep 16 09:01:01 localhost anacron[22386]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Sep 16 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[22388]: finished 0anacron
Sep 16 09:10:01 localhost CROND[22393]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 16 09:20:01 localhost CROND[22400]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 16 09:30:01 localhost CROND[22409]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 16 09:40:01 localhost CROND[22421]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep 16 09:50:01 localhost CROND[22432]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

Have been checking the configurations files in `logrotate.d` and everything seems normal, **what can possibly leaving my cron hanging ?**

Comment: All your redirection does is capture any regular output and errors from logrotate and throws them away.  That's the exact opposite of what you want when you're trying to troubleshoot a program.  Have you tried running the script as it was originally from the command line?

Comment: What happens if you run the program manually - does it still hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone left a squid configuration file in `logrotate` with the following configuration:

```
/dir/user/logs/squid/* {
    weekly
    rotate 5
    compress
    notifempty
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
      # Asks squid to reopen its logs. (log_rotate 0 is set in squid.conf)
      # errors redirected to make it silent if squid is not running
      /usr/sbin/squid -k rotate 2>/dev/null
      # Wait a little to allow Squid to catch up before the logs is compressed
      sleep 1
    endscript
}
```

The problem in that configuration is that it is rotating every single file, including the already compressed files, leavinf me with million of multiple times compressed files and their offspring. The configuration should be to include the `*.log*` and not all `*`:

```
/dir/user/logs/squid/*.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Debug your logrotate configuation by running the logrotate command manually from the command line with the `--debug` or `--verbose` option to see where and why it hangs.

Comment: I think it is. There are lots of reasons why `logrotate` might hang, and running it interactively with `--verbose` is *the* way to find out the one that applies in your case. In my experience, it prints much more than what you cited, and you also get a chance to look at `ps` and `lsof`output in parallel while it is apparently hanging.